# What are FIX-Protocol 4.4 CURRENCY DERIVATIVES ( futures / options ) TAGS?

Tags: fix-protocol, financial, trading, quantitative-finance, algorithmic-trading

I have to implement Currency derivatives for Institutional model.

We have a trading application.

I would like to know are there any specific FIX-Protocol tags which are received or are to be sent from FIDESSA/BLOOMBERG terminals for **Currency Derivative Trading**?

For ex: a tag  **`21=`** ( `{1|2|3}-`indicating if it's BEST or DMA ).

Or they use the same set of tags which are generally used for Equity derivatives.

I would really appreciate if someone has a log or something or if someone can post a FIX-Protocol string for an **Order Instruction** for Currency Derivative trading.

Comment: Nobody will share FIX messages with you, that may amount to stealing in the current scenario. Go through your FIX spec agreed with your counterparty. TO construct a FIX message check any of the online message viewer like Fiximate etc.

Comment: i know that all i want to know is when someone places an order for a currency future or currency options,are there any specific tags that would be coming on the FIX engine from the client.

Comment: As Rupert has already noted, your (company) primary step is to source the vendor-specific details from FIX-Protocol service provider ( they may and do have private protocol adaptations and/or extensions, that you need to integrate against ). Next, your (company) next step is to define use-case patterns, that your (company) side plans to deploy and that are the items your (company) test-plan shall contain for the FIX-Protocol integration (a mandatory Provider - Customer acceptance) testing. There is a common practice to hire FIX-Protocol expert for this. It's Bu$ine$$, not a DIY/hackathon trial